# How to Dynamic SQL Pivoting?

Tags: sql, oracle

I found an [article](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/) about dynamic pivoting in oracle. The solution there looks good, but when I try the following example from that site, I get an ORA-00940 error.

```
select *
from   table( pivot(' select deptno
                      ,      job
                      ,      avg(sal) sal_avg
                      from   emp
                      group
                      by     deptno
                      ,      job
                    ')
            );
```

The query results in these error:

```
FEHLER in Zeile 2:
ORA-00904: "PIVOT": ung³ltiger Bezeichner
```

I found many other sites, that link to the article about, but nowhere stood that the query doesn't work. Only a few blogger said that they not proven it. 
So, work these aproach for someone, maybe with little modifications?

The query should get the same result as the following non dynamic sql:

```
select deptno, clerk, salesman,
       manager, analyst, president
  from (select deptno, job, sal
          from scott.emp )
 pivot( avg(sal) for job in
 ( 'CLERK' as clerk,
   'SALESMAN' as salesman,
   'MANAGER' as manager,
   'ANALYST' as analyst,
   'PRESIDENT' as president ) )
 order by deptno;
```

The expected result looks like:

```
    DEPTNO      CLERK   SALESMAN    MANAGER    ANALYST  PRESIDENT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10       1300                  2450                  5000
        20        950                  2975       3000
        30        950       1400       2850
```

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: It looks from the link like you need to implement that `PIVOT()` table function as well as install some extensions to Oracle to get it to work. I do know that pivoting in Oracle 11g is not dynamic - the values have to be listed explicitly.

Comment: Ok, found a zip with the implementation of the pivot function at the bottom of that site.

Comment: There is link to code in this article that created pivot() function. There is pivot/unpivot operators in Oracle: http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php